# Bootstrap popover NOT working when triggered from inside of a Google visualization chart (table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization, popover

I have a sitiuation with Twitter Bootsrap popovers. I managed to make them work to show remote content via iframes, but the problem is I have a Google visualization chart (table) and it has links to trigger popovers depending on the cells values.
The table visualization is set to allow html and it works okay even to trigger modals, but not popovers. They just work when outside of the table.

For you guys to have an idea of what's going on I've placed the full code in jsFidle.http://jsfiddle.net/TyPowers/xLkcY/
Though external references are loaded in the same order (which happens to be an issue sometimes), in jsFidle the popoovers outside of the table don't work either.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
    var img = '<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="220" width="420"
src="http://dxlite.g7vjr.org/?dx=LU5DX&limit=10"></iframe>';
    $("#blob").popover({title: 'Last 10 spots for the selected station', 
content: img, html:true});
    $('[rel="popover"]').popover();
    })
    });
```

So to see the actual issue please take a look at http://qsl.net/lu5dx/dxo/ 
The comment in the first record of the table has exactly the same code as the popoevers outside of the table, but it doesn't work. Someone suggested placing a span class, but it didn't work either.
Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've actually loaded Bootstrap in your fiddle.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for looking into it. Actually Bootstrap 3.0.0 is loaded, otherwise the page won't show like it does. Check the external references and open the frame and view source code. All I need is there.

Comment: It does not work here - `Cannot read property 'applyFilter' of null` and the chart never shows up.

Comment: Google visualization issue. Try reloading the page. The live example is up and running though I cannot view it with FireFox, but with Chrome, Opera and IE it works okay. http://qsl.net/lu5dx/dxo/

Comment: I've changed the code of the control filter wrapper causing that, so there should not be any errors on page load.

Comment: I'm seeing an error (both on jsfiddle and qsl.net) `The filter cannot operate on a column of type string. Column type must be one of: number, date, datetime or timeofday. Column role must be domain, and correlate to a continuous axis.`.

Comment: Hi asgallant. I'm able to see it from three computers here using Chrome, Opera and IE (not FF). Please try reloading the page several times. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got it to load finally, and figured out why your popovers aren't working; see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do to fix the popover links is initialize them in a "ready" event handler for the table.  Add this to your `drawVisualization` function after you create the `cTable` object, but before calling the dashboard's `#draw` method:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(cTable, 'ready', function () {
    $('#' + cTable.getContainerId() + ' [rel="popover"]').popover();
});
```

A few other things to note that might help: you don't need to pre-load the "table" and "corechart" packages - the ChartWrapper and ControlWrapper objects will take care of loading the necessary libraries for you (preloading doesn't hurt, but it's not going to gain you anything either).  You also don't need to specify the `dataTable` parameter for the `ChartRangeFilter` - that is handled by the `Dashboard`.  The `ChartRangeFilter` `minRangeSize` option is a sub-option of the `ui` option, not `ui.chartOptions`, so it should be set up like this:

```
options: {
    ui: {
        chartOptions: {
            height: 70,
            chartArea: {'height': '80%', 'width': '99.5%'},
            width: '100%',
            hAxis: {
                format: 'MMM d y'
            },
            label : 'End Date Filter'
        },
        // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86,400,000
        minRangeSize: 86400000,
        chartView: {
            // Display a single series (DXPedition End Date) to filter the table visualization.
            columns: [7, {type: 'number', calc: function() { return 0;}}]
        }
    },
    // Filter by the DXPedition End Date axis.
    filterColumnIndex: 7
}
```

Also, it might help with the data-loading problem if you switch the spreadsheet url to use the `tq` parameter instead of the `ccc` parameter:

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0AmR-D3rOsulZdDJtbmxWeVdXLUliSEhRV0gwNUZsbUE');
```

The `tq` parameter tells the spreadsheet API to return a DataTable object.  I changed this in a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/xLkcY/10/, also contains the other changes from above) and noticed a dramatic reduction in the number of loading errors (though they did not go away entirely).

Comment: Asgallant!! I OWE you!. You simply rock buddy. Thank you so very much. I really asked people that I believe are Js gurus and they are still trying to figure it out. I have no words to thank you enough. If you ever visit Argentina I'll bake my best pizzas for ya! Regards.